# Transfering raster attributes to a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes

I am using Arc GIS 10.2.  I have a raster layer and a shapefile layer. I would like to transfer the attributes of the raster layer to the shapefile layer using a majority rule. The raster layer is a lower resolution version of the shapefile layer with different attributes that I would like to have included with the higher resolution shapefile. I want to keep the attributes of the polygons in the shapefile layer and add the attributes from the raster shapes that make up the majority of each shapefile polygons.

Comment: Do you have the Spatial Analyst Extension?

Answer (score 3):

The*Add Surface Information* tool in the 3D Analyst toolbox will transfer the pixel value of a raster layer to the vector data.  For example, if you have a point dataset, each point aquire a new attribute that stores the pixel value at that point.  The raster and the vector data need to reference the same coordinate system or the Add Surface Information tool will return an error.

Comment: What is up with this editing comment? I provided a three sentence (4 line) answer that completely addressed the question, provided some general guidance as to what to expect, and addressed the one major pitfall with the tool.  What is wrong with brevity?  I will add a link to the tool help next time.

Comment: I believe the comment is to do with your previous answer with just one line ( before you made the edit). I am not sure though